# Hide table, when tbody missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

My program generate tables, some with `tbody`, some without `tbody`:

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any way by which the table isn't displayed if the `tbody` is missing? (as in the third table)

Comment: Not reliably, because most browsers will insert a `<tbody>` if it's omitted (despite the `<tbody>` being an optional element); which means you have to parse the HTML with regex: and you should (probably) [never parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/82548). But looking at your question more closely, you seem to mean "...if the `tbody` is *empty*" rather than 'missing'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try to browse all `table` and check if the tbody of that table is empty:

```js
$("table").each(function(i,v){
   if($(this).find("tbody").html().trim().length === 0){
       $(this).hide()
   }
})
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this. Check for each table if the tbody has children elements.

```
$("table").each(function(){
   if($(this + "tbody").children().length == 0){
       $(this).parent().hide();
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking if the tbody is empty

```
$("table").each(function(i,v){
   if($(this).find("tbody").children().length){
       $(this).parent().hide();
   }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `jQuery.filter` function to locate all tables that have empty `tbody`, and hide them:

```
$("table").filter(function(){
    return $(this).find("tbody > *").length === 0;
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the [`.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) function.

First hide all tables:

```
$("table").hide();
```

Then show only the ones that have a `tbody`:

```
$("table").has("tbody").show();
```

Or if the `tbody` has cells (not empty):

```
$("table").has("tbody td").show();
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fsfs5fmk/)

Answer (score 0):

If only using html and css and you don't want to show non filled tables just delete the third table from your html code or add this to your third table

```
<table style="display:none">
...
</table>
```

**EDIT:** If you are using Javascript of Php, JSTL you can modify your view to hide tables